# Dataframe - Calculated Column based on 2 criteria to find day/night

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a **Date** column and a **Toggle** column, which is True when the sun goes down. 
Now, I need a calculated column that says if it is night or day.

[image]

It is **day** until it is **true**, then it is night until the **date** column changes.

I created some code, but I am not happy with it as it is inefficient (for loop).

```
for i in range(0, len(DF)): 

    j = DF.columns.get_loc('Toggle') 
    k = DF.columns.get_loc('Day/Night')  # This is just a copy of the index which is datetime
    l = DF.columns.get_loc('Date')  

    if DF.iat[i, j] == True:  
        DF['Day/Night'].values[i] = 'Night'

    elif DF.iat[i - 1, k] == 'Night' and DF.iat[i, l] == DF.iat[i - 1, l]:  
        DF['Day/Night'].values[i] = 'Night'

    else:

        DF['Day/Night'].values[i] = 'Day'
```

```
Date,Toggle
11/11/2018,FALSE
11/11/2018,FALSE
11/11/2018,TRUE
11/11/2018,FALSE
11/11/2018,FALSE
11/11/2018,FALSE
11/12/2018,FALSE
11/12/2018,FALSE
11/12/2018,FALSE
11/12/2018,TRUE
11/12/2018,FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
indicator = df.groupby('Date')['Toggle'].cumsum()

df['Day/Night'] = np.where(indicator, 'Night', 'Day')

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         Date  Toggle Day/Night
0  2018-11-11   False       Day
1  2018-11-11   False       Day
2  2018-11-11    True     Night
3  2018-11-11   False     Night
4  2018-11-11   False     Night
5  2018-11-11   False     Night
6  2018-11-12   False       Day
7  2018-11-12   False       Day
8  2018-11-12   False       Day
9  2018-11-12    True     Night
10 2018-11-12   False     Night
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` assignment and groupby `ffill` and `fillna`

```
df.loc[df.Toggle, 'Day/Night'] = 'Night'
df['Day/Night'] = df['Day/Night'].groupby(df.Date).ffill().fillna('Day')

Out[588]:
          Date  Toggle Day/Night
0   11/11/2018   False       Day
1   11/11/2018   False       Day
2   11/11/2018    True     Night
3   11/11/2018   False     Night
4   11/11/2018   False     Night
5   11/11/2018   False     Night
6   11/12/2018   False       Day
7   11/12/2018   False       Day
8   11/12/2018   False       Day
9   11/12/2018    True     Night
10  11/12/2018   False     Night
```